# Encryption Security Standards in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption

I'm looking to do encryption where "**the client**" uses a publicly available key from "**the server**" to encrypt a message that will be seen by "**the enemy**". It is important that "**the enemy**" is not able to decipher the message. Furthermore, "**the enemy**" will be responsible for delivering the encrypted message and "**the server**" must be able to detect if the message been tampered with. Lastly, it is important that "**the client**" is not be able to determine the private key of the server (based on how the message is encrypted; although I think this goes without saying).

I'm looking to do it in **Ruby** and I'm very out of touch with modern security and encryption methods. Any getting started hints, links or snippets would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds a lot like [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) combined with a symmetric-key block cipher if the message is longer than the key length. That, and what you seem to be looking for, also pretty much describes how [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) works.

I haven't used it myself but there's an [OpenPGP Ruby](https://github.com/bendiken/openpgp) gem for that.

> $ sudo gem install openpgp

Answer (score 0):

There's is chilkat library that can help you with encryption. Check this site for different encryption snippets in ruby http://www.example-code.com/ruby/encryption.asp

Also these gems might help
http://ezcrypto.rubyforge.org/

http://crypt.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really not sure what the standard I'm looking for is called. I was hoping someone with some experience in encryption could provide a bit more guidens.

Comment: Ill prefer that you first go thru the encryption algorithms  http://www.mycrypto.net/encryption/crypto_algorithms.html and make a decision of which ruby gems actually matches your requirement. You can also check this post http://stuff-things.net/2008/02/05/encrypting-lots-of-sensitive-data-with-ruby-on-rails/ though it is more pointed towards rails, it should give you an idea of how encryption can be done using ruby.